# How do I get a thicker drop shadow on my ToolTip?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tooltip

I'm overriding my tooltips with the following:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ToolTip}" TargetType="ToolTip">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush />
                    </Grid.Background>
                    <mwt:SystemDropShadowChrome Color="#00FFFFFF" CornerRadius="5" Name="Shdw" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Border CornerRadius="5">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <ContentPresenter TextBlock.Foreground="Black" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </mwt:SystemDropShadowChrome>
                </Grid>
```

The Thickness value for the margin seems to have a maximum value of 5?

```
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ToolTipService.HasDropShadow">
                        <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" TargetName="Shdw">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <Thickness>0,0,5,5</Thickness>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Trigger.Value>
                            <sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean>
                        </Trigger.Value>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

It would be nice to be able to see more of the dropshadow.

My bad for not posting all my code. Here it is with an edit based on the response from icebat:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ToolTip}" TargetType="ToolTip">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush />
                    </Grid.Background>
                    <mwt:SystemDropShadowChrome Color="#71000000" CornerRadius="5" Name="Shdw" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Border CornerRadius="5">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <ContentPresenter TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="ClearType" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" TextBlock.FontFamily="Segoe UI" TextBlock.FontStretch="Normal" TextBlock.FontWeight="Normal" TextBlock.Foreground="Black" TextBlock.FontSize="13" Margin="18,8,16,4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                                <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" BorderBrush="Gray" Margin="10,5,10,5"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                                    <TextBlock Margin="8,4,0,0" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{x:Static res:AppStrings.Help_0_Footer}" FontSize="13" Foreground="#E3000000" />
                                </Border>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush.StartPoint>
                                        <Point X=".5" Y="0"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush.StartPoint>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush.EndPoint>
                                        <Point X=".5" Y="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush.EndPoint>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFA200" Offset="1"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.305"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                        </Border>
                    </mwt:SystemDropShadowChrome>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ToolTipService.HasDropShadow" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Shdw" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I still don't get a thicker dropshadow for a margin larger than 5.

Comment: No. I posted the code above with your suggestion, but the margin still has no effect past 5. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Margin is not limited. To see more of the shadow you need to apply margin not to the `SystemDropShadowChrome` decorator itself but to its content:

```
<mwt:SystemDropShadowChrome Name="Shdw" CornerRadius="5">
    <Border Name="shdwContent" CornerRadius="5">
         <StackPanel>
             <ContentPresenter TextBlock.Foreground="Black" />
         </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</mwt:SystemDropShadowChrome>
...
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="ToolTipService.HasDropShadow" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="ShdwContent" Value="0,0,5,5">
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

And as a side note, right now you are using transparent color as shadow color (`#00FFFFFF`). If that`s not changed with some triggers or by other means, you won`t see any shadow.